# Does any browser or plugin have a 1 click means to surf securely? 

Tags: security, browser, browsing

I don't mean anonymously so much as I mean turn off JavaScript, Flash, and anything else that potentially has a virus.  I recognize the UX goes way down, but that's one reason this has to be easy.

Do any browsers support a mode for surfing the web on untrusted sites in such a manner?  IE it seems you need to check 20 different options or go into a menu 7 clicks deep.  This is not what I am looking for.

Does any browser support a 1 click toggling approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not out of the box, no.

However, there are addons which will do this. The most popular and well-done of these is [NoScript](http://noscript.net/). NoScript will block all script execution, plugins (Flash, Java, etc.) unless the origin domain has been whitelisted by you. This *will* break some websites, but you can always select "Temporarily Allow *example.com*" from NoScript's menu to allow a particular domain for the session. It also offers some [other hardening features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript#Features).

NoScript is exclusively for Firefox, however a version for Chrome called [NotScripts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odjhifogjcknibkahlpidmdajjpkkcfn) is available.

Comment: This is a great tool.  Albeit, its cumbersome in that it blocks by default.  I would really like if it operated inversely.  In other words, I do not want it to block unless I say "start blocking".  I tend to visit the same or similar sites.  On occasion, I want to surf dangerously.  So, to have this on all the time is an annoyance as it makes my "normal" sites stop functioning without extensive configuration.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey You can permanently allow a domain if you visit it often and don't want to have to enable scripts each time you do so. Alternatively, NoScript can operate in [Blacklist Mode](http://noscript.net/features#blacklist) wherein all domains are allowed to run scripts and plugins _except_ those you specifically blacklist. Other security features of NoScript, like clickjacking protection will still be globally enforced in this mode.